# Ajax call not working with web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, .net-4.5, webmethod

I need to call a web method from Ajax call. See the below code which I'm using 
to make the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("WebForm1.aspx/CampaignData") %>',
    data: '{"CampName":' + params + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (str) {
        // Handle success
        alert("Success call");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle error
        alert("Fails");
    }

});
```

My web method is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CampaignData(string CampName)
{
    return CampName;
}
```

Comment: What config changes need to be done to use Ajax in .Net4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using .Net 4.0 after change the flowing thing it started hitting the web method break point.
Inside ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs change:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

To:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

(Or just comment the line)

Also if friendly URLs are enabled you need to change

```
url: "ConsultaPedidos.aspx/GetClients",
```

To:

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("ConsultaPedidos.aspx/GetClients") %>',
```

Hope this help somebody else